# Unable to connect to root profile or open root console in Kali Linu

Tags: linux, grub, login, kali-linux, root

I am running Kali Linux on VirtualBox. When I try to login into the root account it just does not connect. the same if I enter a non-root account and try sudo commands. I entered the grub bootloader and tried to reset the password with [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ON41kMtk_Mg) and it writes an error:

[image: x]

I recently made a script and tried to make a shortcut to it in the terminal, and I'm afraid that's the problem. I followed the first answer in [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118312/how-can-i-create-a-custom-terminal-command-to-run-a-script).

I need to reset the password.

Comment: I think newer (2020) versions of Kali do not have an explicit Root user. The user you set up with should have admin credentials if you start a command with "sudo" .  I do this and it works fine.  My own Kali here as a Virtual Machine started in 2019 and upgraded so it does have a Root user but I do not use it. I can update , install and so on from my normal user starting with "sudo" .  Works.

Comment: i tried adding a user but somehow the password changed

Comment: Try the following with your user, ie. existing user:  usermod -a -G sudo username  (your user).  To add a user like this:  useradd -m username , then add to "sudoers" group as above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by mounting the current machine to another one